"find" command does not find all files from root unless folder is specified
I am trying to find the files that are named setenv.sh on this machine, I am logged in as root and am searching from the '/' using the following syntax and receiving the output:
# First 
[root@machine1 ~]# find / -name setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-8.20.15-standalone/bin/setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.4.11-standalone/bin/setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.4.14-standalone/bin/setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.4.17-standalone/bin/setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.12.4-standalone/bin/setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.14.1-standalone/bin/setenv.sh

Now, output above does not include all occurrences of setenv.sh that should be on the machine and unless I do specify the directory closer to the missing file I wont get output location I was searching for, like so:
# Second
[root@machine1 ~]# find /opt/atlassian/jira/ -name setenv.sh
/opt/atlassian/jira/bin/setenv.sh

Doing find /opt/ -name setenv.sh or find /opt/atlassian/ -name setenv.sh returns the first output.
MY QUESTION: Why the second output was not included in the first one, because AFAIK it should be because find should output everything on the system that matches since it starts from the search from /?

What is the output of ls -ld /opt/atlassian/jira? Note the lack of trailing slash.

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 57 Mar 26 15:17 /opt/atlassian/jira -> /opt/atlassian/atlassian-jira-software-9.14.1-standalone/
Ok, that does explain things, the jira dir was linked and find does not follow links by default, so it was technically included already
